# AWS EC2 Mern Stack Application Axios

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, axios, mern

Hello Im trying to configure my MERN stack app because I will deploy it to AWS EC2,

In my front end, I have this API request

```
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then((response) => {
            if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } else {
                navigate("/" , {replace: true})
            }
        })
```

But http://localhost:3001/login
request will obviously not work and I'll get an error when I deploy it to AWS EC2. What is the correct URL in there when I deploy my app to AWS EC2?

For example if I want to get this

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.voter) {
        res.send({loggedIn: true, user: req.session.voter})
    } else {
        res.send({loggedIn: false})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `localhost` to the public IP of the EC2 instance, or the public DNS name.